# How to send invites to friends using Facebook instant game SDK with Phaser framework

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-instant-games

Iam currently working on a Facebook instant game project. I need to implement friend invites for my instant game project which uses Phaser framework. I searched but I couldnt find any working or tutorials, the docs is not making sense to me.Could anyone help?

Links, Videos will be helpful.

I tried looking for Game requests link in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests/

But this one uses fb module and instant game is using FBInstant module. I am confused with that.

Answer (score 0):

For FB instant apps there is no need of using FB module. Using FBInstant Module is the way. All the available API for this available only on the below link, based on your version.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/sdk/fbinstant6.2

No any other resource than this for the docs (as of this is posted)

Theres a group in Facebook which is pretty good. Helpful.

Join there for more on Instant Games Development.

https://www.facebook.com/groups/instantgamedevelopers

For Invites createAsync( )/updateAsync( ) can be used.

Comment: I am using chooseAsync() for selecting users. However, when I select a user that never played with me before, I would like to be able to 'invite' her to the game through messenger. How do I do this? Do I need a bot to do this?